# Eclipse PHP debugging as "CLI application" does not stop at breakpoints nor first line (using zend xdebug)

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug

Hello I'm using Eclipse 2023-06 (4.28.0)

I used PHP that I copied form WAMP64 c:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.0.26\ to c:\Prog\php8.0.26\

I configured in eclipse: Window->Preferences->PHP->Installed PHP->Add

[image]

And on debug  tab was preconfigured:

[image]

In my c:\Prog\php8.0.26\php.ini I set xdebug.mode=debug and xdebug.log_level=10

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.26/zend_ext/php_xdebug-3.1.6-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll"
;zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.26/zend_ext/php_xdebug-3.2.2-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll"
;xdebug.mode allowed are : off develop coverage debug gcstats profile trace
xdebug.mode =debug
xdebug.output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.log="c:/wamp64/logs/xdebug.log"
;xdebug.log_level : 0 Criticals, 1 Connection, 3 Warnings, 5 Communication, 7 Information, 10 Debug Breakpoint
xdebug.log_level=7
xdebug.profiler_output_name=trace.%H.%t.%p.cgrind
xdebug.use_compression=false
```

then I set Run->Debug (as)-> selected "PHP CLI application"

PHP was executed and echo from it was printed but breakpoint was not hit. And in right bottom corner it was written lunching and freezed at 45%.

How to make debugger working and stopping at breakpoint?

Answer (score 1):

So I after trying what not... I looked into:
c:/wamp64/logs/xdebug.log

and found:

```
[20988] Log opened at 2023-08-25 12:31:47.962528
[20988] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Found 'XDEBUG_CONFIG' ENV variable
[20988] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9003.
[20988] [Step Debug] ERR: Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
[20988] Log closed at 2023-08-25 12:31:48.385527
enter code here
```

Obviously default eclipse port is not fitting with default zend xdebug port... Great...

Anyway now solution is to change port.
Either in eclipse fill 9003.
or in you php.ini set:

```
xdebug.client_port = 9000
```

works for me...